# .Net Integration Timeout

Tags: integration, .net

When we use the following code for the authenticaiton, its gettign too much of time for get the result. is there any way to optimize the code?

```
loginResult = SFDCServices.login(userName, passwordToken);
Services.Url = loginResult.serverUrl;
Services.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader();
Services.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = loginResult.sessionId;
```

Answer (score -1):

A timeout during a login sequence suggests that there is a network connectivity problem. Your client may reside behind a proxy or firewall, or your routing tables are misconfigured. If it's a proxy, you'll need to navigate through it using SOCKS or whatever protocol your proxy expects. If it's a firewall, you'll need to allow connections to the salesforce.com servers on port 443 (SSL/TLS port). If the problem has to do with routing tables, you may need to reconfigure your network or run a trace route to determine where the problem is. In any event, the problem directly has nothing to do with your code or the salesforce.com service. A login call typically returns in a fraction of a second, unless you have a very large password (such as a million character password), and even then it should return before a network timeout.

Comment: Thanks. i think so many query am using so can we get the modyfied user name by using the formula field? i got id only. so how to get the user name?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but if you'd clarify, I will be glad to try and help you.

Comment: How can i get the modified username form the perticualr record. i have quereid but i got the modifed user id only. so i would like to get the user name form the modified id. NOTE: I DONT WANT QUERY THE USER OBJECT WITH THAT ID.